# Drop-down menu in CSS

Tags: css, navigationbar

I was trying to build a drop-down multi-level navigation menu bar in pure CSS.
Here is the code (I know it turns out ugly):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Menu</title>
 <style>
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
 }
 ul {
  list-style: none
 }
 li {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink
 }
 li > ul {
  display: none
 }
 li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 120px;
  background: red
 }
 #nav > li:hover > ul {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px
 }
 li:hover {
  background: red
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="nav">
  <li>1
   <ul>
    <li>1.1
     <ul>
      <li>1.1.1
       <ul>
        <li>1.1.1.1</li>
        <li>1.1.1.2</li>
        <li>1.1.1.3</li>
        <li>1.1.1.4</li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li>1.1.2</li>
      <li>1.1.3</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>1.2</li>
    <li>1.3</li>
    <li>1.4</li>
    <li>1.5</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The code runs fine under Firefox20 but in IE10 it is off by 1px up, and in Chrome26 it is off by 1px down. I think it is because the browsers render the list layout differently. Any help would be appreciated!

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Class/ShZk8/)

Comment: have a look at http://cssmenumaker.com/ for some insight/inspiration,..

Comment: @lukeocom thanks for your reply. Actually I did something similar as the link you provided. However they only accept one or two layers of submenu. This time I am trying for a general solution for any layers of submenu, which may not be as pretty, but challenging to me:)

Comment: yes I noticed that too. I used a site to generate a css menu with multiple levels. I'll try find that site again and post you the link. The resulting menu wasnt as fancy looking as those from the above link, but the css was.

Comment: I think this was it... http://pure-css-menu-maker.en.softonic.com/ I took the resulting menu and reverse engineered the css, removing everything that wasnt needed and trimming it down to be specific for my needs. It provides a pretty clean css approach. May be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend starting with a reset stylesheet so that you clear any of the browser set styles.  Then each browser will start from an even playing field.  The browsers will not render the lists differently.

For more info on reset stylesheets see http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually "line-height" has caused the problem.